# Unsetting parameters for specific hosts in SSH config

Tags: ssh, openssh

In `.ssh/config`, I have set a `RemoteForward` for all hosts in a given domain:

```
Host *.[domain]
   RemoteForward [remote-port] 127.0.0.1:[local-port]
```

How do I unset that parameter for a specific host within that domain (e.g., `git.[domain]`)?

Comment: The `ssh_config` manpage mentions the use of negation to exclude certain hosts, but only for keys in the `.ssh/authorized_keys`. Have tried similar combinations in `.ssh/config` but no dice

Comment: From the manpage I'd expect `Host !git.[domain],*.[domain]` to do what you want. What are the combinations you tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the ClearAllForwardings setting:

```
Host *.[domain]
   RemoteForward [remote-port] 127.0.0.1:[local-port]

Host git.[domain]
   ClearAllForwardings yes
```

Does git not automatically set ClearAllForwardings=yes, as scp and sftp do?

Comment: It does not seem to. I had set `RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698` on top of `~/.ssh/config` to use [rsub](https://github.com/henrikpersson/rsub) on all domains, but then started getting `Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698` when connecting to GitHub (since it obviously doesn't allow forwarding a port). With `ClearAllForwardings=yes` under `Host github.com` the error went away.